# How to catch tab change event in streamlit

Tags: tabs, streamlit

I am new to Streamlit and would like it to be able to detect when I switch from one tab to another, so it can perform certain specific reactions. I am aware that Streamlit does not have a built-in tab change event. Are there any solutions to this issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There was already a discussion about that on a stramlit forum, in short, tabs are just visual elements, they don't have events, but they introduced an alternative component on this [github](https://github.com/Mohamed-512/Extra-Streamlit-Components), called "TabBarItemData"